# Stripping JSON element and adding a new one to it

Tags: json, shell, jq

I am trying to take an existing JSON element and create a new one with an added value for a key.

I know I can use a multitude of other tools to do this but I am wondering if this is possible with jq alone

input json file:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "uuid": "1a03",
      "enabled": true,
      "autoname": true,
      "name": "LBC",
      "number": 0,
      "epgauto": true,
      "epggrab": [],
      "dvr_pre_time": 0,
      "dvr_pst_time": 0,
      "epg_running": -1,
      "services": [
        "ea8"
      ],
      "tags": [
        "0a7"
      ],
      "bouquet": ""
    },
    {
      "uuid": "4a05",
      "enabled": true,
      "autoname": true,
      "name": "Radio X",
      "number": 0,
      "epgauto": true,
      "epggrab": [],
      "dvr_pre_time": 0,
      "dvr_pst_time": 0,
      "epg_running": -1,
      "services": [
        "9d36"
      ],
      "tags": [
        "08fa7"
      ],
      "bouquet": ""
    },...]
}
```

I then filter this for the object that I want which then returns a single object.

I have unsuccessfully tried using map "+" operator to add values I think my syntax might be wrong

I am using this to filter on the object I want

`.entries[] | select(.uuid=="4a05")`

I want to create the following output if I ended up filtering on `uuid=4a05`

`[{"tags":["08fa7","MYNEWVALUE"],"number":mynew##,"uuid":"4a05"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish the task - first create an object with the fields of interest, and then update `.tags`:

```
.entries[]
| select(.uuid=="4a05") 
| {tags, uuid, number: "mynew##"}
| .tags += ["MYNEWVALUE"]
```

Comment: amazing! Is there something I could do to check if the value I am adding already exists?

Comment: Yes, of course. You might like to work your way through the jq tutorial and familiarize yourself with the online manual. Just follow the links at the top of https://stedolan.github.io/jq/